# "For another time" vs. "Another time"

Tags: phrase-usage, word-difference

I wrote this sentence:

> The user may modify the letter or listen to the word **for** another time.

Just I don't know whether I could or should write it without "for"? Then, what would be the difference?

Comment: Do you mean that they can repeat listening to the word?

Comment: Do you mean "again"? Because if you mean again, I'd just say that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes, do you mean the right phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, "once more", "again", or "another time" would all work. "For another time", though, suggests that they can only listen to it at a time that is not the present: they're saving it for later. (Phrased the way it is in the question, it doesn't really make any sense, but that would be the closest to the usual understanding.)

Comment: You mean "for another time" always means "later" or "in future" or "at another time"?

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes to all of those.